# How did Eurus get to know about the outside world while she was living in solitary?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

I recently watched the *Sherlock* TV series again. One thing is bugging me: how could Eurus Holmes tell Mycroft about the upcoming terrorist attack in London? I mean, according to Mycroft, Eurus had no contact with outside world (until she met Moriarty) so she would have had no idea what events were occurring.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! I hope you don't mind me cleaning up the question's grammar a little. As for your question, I must admit I never watched the Series 4 finale, but if Eurus had been in contact with Moriarty, isn't it possible Moriarty knew about the attack, and told her?

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up! According to the Series 4 finale, as I remember Eurus got the chance of meeting Moriarity when she told about those attacks to Mycroft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Eurus recruited those sent in to her presence, allowing her more and more control at Sherrinford

Although Eurus was notionally in solitary confinement at Sherrinford, the governor did not keep sufficiently close control over who was allowed contact with her.

> MYCROFT: Has there ever been, against my express instructions, any attempt at a psychiatric evaluation of Eurus Holmes?
>
> GOVERNOR: Yes.

Eurus then used her manipulative gifts to 'recruit' them to serve her agenda rather than the facility.

> GOVERNOR: Everyone we sent in there ... it's hard to describe, it's like she...
>
> HOLMES: Recruited them?
>
> GOVERNOR: Enslaved them.
>
> HOLMES: She's been capable of that since she was five, she's an adult now!

**As she gradually asserted increasing control at Sherrinford, Eurus would have gained access to news of the outside world, and any contacts from the world of crime.**

Comment: IMO it's not fair to say that Eurus was only interested in world of crime though, she isn't your ordinary criminal. even Moriarty was created by her